# c# BindingList problem

Tags: c#, bindinglist

I have interface defs like below.

```
public interface IProvider  
{  

}


public interface IProviderList : BindingList<IProvider>  
{

}
```

Not sure whygetting compilation error
Type 'BindingList<...>' in interface list is not an interface

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BindingList<T>` is not an interface, it's a class. `IBindingList` is an interface. Perhaps you meant to use `IBindingList`?

Comment: Oh sorry yes i should have used the interface but doing that giving me error "The non-generic type 'System.ComponentModel.IBindingList' cannot be used with type arguments". Not sure if its doable

Comment: IBindingList is not generic, so no, you cannot do "IBindingList<T>" unless you create such an interface yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`BindingList<T>` is a class.
An interface (your `IProviderList`) can not inherit from a class.